# How to access files in my public folder in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to access files located in my *public* folder, using express. 
My file structure looks like this

```
/app
 -app.js
 /routes
  -index.js
 /public
  /images
   /misc
   -background.jpg
  /css
    -style.css
```

My *app.js* is running on port *3000*,

```
app.use(express.static('app/public'));
app.use(require('./routes/index'));
```

and *index.js* cannot find *background.jpg* or *style.css*

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send(`
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="css/style.css">
<h1>Welome</h1>
<img
src="/images/misc/background.jpg"
style="height:300px;"/>
<p>some text</p>`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am going by the docs so I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: so, if you go to `http://localhost:3000/css/style.css`, what exactly ***do*** you get?

Comment: Cannot GET /css/style.css

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As your `app.js` and `public` folders are inside the app folder, you don't need to include the `app` folder in `express.static('app/public')` and also use `path.resolve` as below,

```
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

Also, change the `href` value below to `href="/css/style.css"`,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: I explained you the reason above in my answer. It requires absolute path. So you can use path.resolve to convert the current path to absolute path. The current path should be the relative path to app.js file and public folder.

Answer (score 5):

**Require path module in app.js:**

```
var path=require('path');
```

**Modify middle ware for static content:**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

**Link to your css like this:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously an old question, adequately answered, but here's how to make it available at a distinct path

```
app.use('/u/profileImg/', express.static('./userCreated/profileImg/'));
```

Where the first argument is the web-accessible path, and the second argument is the location of the folder.

You can also do

```
app.use('/u/', express.static('./userCreated/'));
```

and `/u/profileImg/` would still be available, as well as the other contents of `/userCreated/`.