# AJAX call to Node.js script fails

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I am very new to Node.js so I am certain I am doing something basic wrong. I am trying to make an AJAX call using jQuery to a simple Node.js script. I have tried several variations on the call, using both `$.post` and `$.ajax`, and I have done a couple of different things with the Node.js script, but I keep getting a 404 response on the call. I have looked at several posts about this error, but I haven't found anything which gets me away from the 404 error my AJAX call returns.

This is the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/myapp",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(cardResponse) {
        console.log(cardResponse);
    }
});
```

I would prefer to use POST, but I tried GET in hopes it would make a difference. I didn't think it would, and I was right.

Here's the Node.js script:

```
#!/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/bin

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/myapp', function (req, res) {
    res.json([{
        id_number: 1234,
        user_name: "Andy"
    }]);
    console.log("Meow");
});

app.get('/myapp', function (req, res) {
    res.json([{
        id_number: 1234,
        user_name: "Andy"
    }]);
    console.log("Meow");
});

app.listen( () => {
    console.log(`Server is running.`);
});
```

I have tried specifying a port on the listen and in the AJAX call. (I read you're not supposed to do that in an AJAX call, but I saw at least one post where someone did so, so I tried it.) On the server, I start the Node.js as expected:

`# node app.js`

What am I doing wrong here? Any advice would be appreciated. I apologize if the answer is already posted somewhere and I missed it in my search for an answer.

Comment: 404 error means that the URL is wrong.

Comment: I know what the 404 means, but I don't understand why I am receiving it. Both scripts are on the same server, so it should be able to find them.

Comment: How do you open your HTML page that has Ajax call? It looks like they are not on the same server unless you use the [middleware that exposes static files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291478/387194) where you can use an HTML file with your script or create a route that will send you an HTML file to the browser.